# Can Google ML KIT barcode scanner detect dim light when image is getting captured via Camera?

Tags: barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I have developed a barcode/QR code scanner app using Firebase ML KIT[link](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/guides) and Camera 1 API. I want to check if ML Kit can detect the dim light in the surrounding so that I can switch on the torch to scan the QR code.

Comment: Have you tried it out using your app? How does it work?

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer? I have the same usecase.